# Strange black background around an WPF Image

Tags: wpf, image, mvvm, visual-studio-2008, border

In a MVVM WPF application I have a border around an image:

```
        <Border x:Name="PhotoBorder"
                    Background="Transparent"
                    Margin="3 0 5 0"
                    Grid.Row="3" Grid.RowSpan="7" 
                    Grid.Column="0"                        
                    Height="110" Width="110"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    CornerRadius="5"
                    BorderThickness="1"
                    BorderBrush="LightSteelBlue">

            <Image x:Name="Photo"                     
                   Margin="3"
                   Height="{Binding ElementName=PhotoBorder, Path=Height-3}"
                   Width="{Binding ElementName=PhotoBorder, Path=Width-3}">
                <Image.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="{Binding Path=PhotoImg, Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=PhotoImg}" Value="{x:Null}">
                                <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Resources/Photo.png"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Image.Style>
            </Image>
        </Border>
```

The problem is that black background is shown around the photo as below:

[image]

It is only happening in case view model property "PhotoImg" is null  in the DataTrigger when attaching directly image "/Resources/Photo.png" to the "Source" property.

.. and I do not know why. Any ideas? Something related to the photo?

The original photo is:

[image]

Note: I am using Visual Studio 2008 and .NET Framework 3.5

Comment: `ImageFormat.Bmp` does not support transparency. Use `Png` instead. Besides that, better don't use `System.Drawing.Bitmap` at all in a WPF application and thus avoid the need for a converter.

Comment: @Clemens The problem is not with the converter. Converter is never executed when this default photo is shown, trigger is thrown instead because initially PhotoImg is always null, so photo.png is always assigned directly without using converter: <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Resources/Photo.png"/>. So if I attach /Resources/Photo.png directly to Source property, and .png background is transparent, I do not understand why it is displayed as black background....

Comment: @Clemens Anyway, I am curious when you say: "better don't use System.Drawing.Bitmap....avoid the need for a converter". Why to avoid it? Also, If I do not use a converter, could you guide me on how to do this without a converter in case PhotoImg property is different from null? Thanks in advance and a lot of thanks for your suggestions and recommendations. They are always welcome.

Comment: "*The problem is not with the converter*" - then why do you show it? And why do you declare the `PhotoImg` property as `System.Drawing.Bitmap` (which is a WinForms class) instead of one of the WPF types `BitmapImage`, `BitmapSource` or `ImageSource`?

Comment: @Clemens I was showing the converter because initially I was thinking this could be the problem but finally I have seen that in case view model property PhotoImg is null, then no converter is used, that is, /Resources/Photo.png is directly attached to WPF image source property. I have deleted the converter from the post. Regarding System.Drawing.Bitmap, yes, you are right, it has no sense to use a WinForms class within a WPF project, so I will change to a WPF type. Anyway, in this case it is not affecting, photo is directly attached, so I suppose there is something related to the border....